# my wordpress theme style error(socialvirall)

Tags: css, wordpress

My site is yamf.us, i am using socialvirall theme. When i am editting style.css, the index page is ok, but page or post error, can you help me to fix this.

My link: http://yamf.us/2015/12/07/listen-to-the-piano-guys-take-you-through-50-years-of-batman/

The link of mythemeshop: http://demo.mythemeshop.com/sociallyviral/2015/12/07/listen-to-the-piano-guys-take-you-through-50-years-of-batman/

Comment: Everything is ok as for me. I only have 2 errors that images missing

Comment: but my site float left, i want it float center, can you help me?

Comment: please look at my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is within this css :

```
div#page.single, #page.error, .woocommerce #page {
    background: #fff;
    float: left; // right here. this is your main container. usually you don't want to have it float
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but if you need that `float:left` the simplest way is to add to `div#page.single, #page.error, .woocommerce #page` this:

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);// Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ 
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);  // IE 9 
      transform: translateX(-50%);
position:relative;
left:50%;
```